# Preventing incorrect User Input from crashing my program

Tags: python, loops, input, biopython, http-error

I am attempting to access a FASTA sequence from a UniProt database.  This currently works when entering the UniProt code in correctly (a 6 digit string of characters, for example P10079), however if entering an incorrect one it crashes my program.  I've attempted to write a loop so the user can re-input another code, until one is correctly entered although I'm still getting errors.  Is this because I haven't used this in a function?
Cheers

```
    #Get User Input and access data from UniProt
user_input = input ("Type in your protein accession code: ")
try:
    handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw(user_input)
except HTTPError as e:
    user_input = input("Invalid UniProt Accession Code\nPlease enter another code:") 
else:
    record = SwissProt.read(handle)
    handle.close()
    print("Searching UniProt... \nFinding Sequence... \nChecking for matches...") 
    print (record.description)
    sequence = record.sequence
    print ("Your Fasta Sequence is: ", sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your [`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) statement will only executed if no exception occurs. So if the first input is invalid, i.e. causes an exception, but not the 2nd input, the whole `else` block will be skipped.

One of the several possibilities would be to put everything in a loop which is executed until `get_sprot_raw` succeeds and then get the sequence information.

```
from Bio import ExPASy
from Bio import SwissProt
from urllib.error import HTTPError  

while True:
    user_input = input ("Type in your protein accession code: ")
    try:
        handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw(user_input)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print("Invalid UniProt Accession Code\nPlease enter another code:")
    else:
        break

record = SwissProt.read(handle)
handle.close()
print("Searching UniProt... \nFinding Sequence... \nChecking for matches...") 
print (record.description)
sequence = record.sequence
print ("Your Fasta Sequence is: ", sequence)
```